# Specify conditional rendering of element inside <ui:repeat>? The <c:if> does not seem to work

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl, el, uirepeat

I am trying to conditionally build a custom list using `<ui:repeat>`. On every occurrence of -1 as item-value in list, I need to add a line break.

I tried to use `<c:if>` inside `<ui:repeat>` for that, but it does not seem to work. It always evaluates `false`.

```
<ul>      
    <ui:repeat value="#{topics.list}" var="topicId" >
        <li>#{topicId}</li>
        <c:if test="#{topicId eq -1}">  <br/>  </c:if>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not with JSTL tags, no. They run during view build time, not during view render time. You can visualize it as follows: when JSF builds the view, JSTL tags run from top to bottom first and the result is a pure JSF component tree. Then when JSF renders the view, JSF components run from top to bottom and the result is a bunch of HTML. So, JSTL and JSF don't run in sync as you'd expect from the coding. At the moment your `<c:if>` JSTL tag tag runs, the `#{topicId}` variable which is set by `<ui:repeat>` JSF component isn't available in the scope.

Instead of using `<c:if>`, you need to specify the condition in the `rendered` attribute of the JSF component of interest. As you've actually none, you could wrap it in a [`<ui:fragment>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html).

```html
<ul>      
    <ui:repeat value="#{topics.list}" var="topicId" >
        <li>#{topicId}</li>
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{topicId eq -1}"><br/></ui:fragment>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Alternatives are [`<h:panelGroup>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/panelGroup.html)

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{topicId eq -1}"><br/></h:panelGroup>
```

or in your specific case [`<h:outputText escape="false">`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html)

```html
<h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{topicId eq -1}" />
```

as both also emits nothing else to the HTML output when no client side attributes are specified.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that's the *wrong* place for a `<br/>`. It would be ignored by any webbrowser respecting the HTML specification. Don't you mean it to be *inside* the `<li>`? Or better, give it a `class` and let CSS give it a `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding your concern raised with usage of <br/>, in my actual scenario there are some elements tht I want to put. I just used them for the question with intentions to simplify.